# Creating a regular expression to match words of varying lengths

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I'm writing a regular expression to parse a logfile and I'm having trouble figuring out how to establish a range(?) of sorts for a particular expression. In this case specifically, my logfile contains various severities:

(['EMERG','ALERT','CRIT','ERR','WARNING','NOTICE','INFO','DEBUG'])

I'm basically wondering how I'd write regular expression to match all of those. I understand most digit work, but characters are posing difficult issues for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this regex will match all these entries: [A-Za-z]{1,}
basically it says match all patterns that have only chars from A to Z or a to z with the lenght of at least one char.

for more information see this: [regex cheat-sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/download/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet-v1/pdf/)

and try your regex here: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: `{1,}` is normally written `+` - you could throw in case insensitivity and then this becomes `(?i)[a-z]+`

Comment: How would I go about doing this with a string of words. For example the log could have a "message" of 10 words in length or 2 words in length.